# How to Convert Time to Indian Format am / pm [laravel]

Tags: laravel

We are Making a Project In Laravel !

How to Convert Time In Indian Format Like

Example : I Want to convert | 2021-04-22 16:09:24 to 2021-04-22 04:09 pm

code to fetch time from table

```
{{ $ad->updated_at }}
```

Comment: `{{ $ad->updated_at->format('Y-m-d h:i a') }}`

Comment: showing same, i want to print Like 2021-04-22 16:09:24 to   2021-04-22 04:09:24 pm

Like indian Timing

Comment: `$ad` is this coming from model ? or query builder ?

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for examples of date formatting in PHP.

You can also check [the documentation for all accepted format parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

For this format, you can use:

```
{{ $ad->updated_at->format('Y-m-d h:i a') }}
```

Where:

- `Y` is A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits (Examples: 1999 or 2003)
- `m` is Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros (01 through 12)
- `d` is Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros (01 to 31)
- `h` is 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros (01 through 12)
- `i` is Minutes with leading zeros (00 to 59)
- `a` is Lowercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem (am or pm)

To also include seconds, use `h:i:s`.

Answer (score 0):

by default laravel model [cast](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting) `created_at` and `updated_at` to `datetime` type so it by default it is [carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) instance if you use `laravel model`

so if your using model then this code will work

```php
{{ $ad->updated_at->format('Y-m-d h:i a') }}
```

and if your using [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) then it is not carbon instance in that case you have to use this

```php
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($ad->updated_at)->format('Y-m-d h:i a') }}
```